# How to trigger file watcher on a entire directory in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript, webstorm, file-watcher

I'm using Webstorm file watcher to compile my CoffeeScript.

My problem is that I have refactored the strutcure of my project's files.

Can I remove all files in /bin directory and tell to webstorm to apply his file watcher compile command on all .coffee files in a directory ? Because I don't want to open, modify and redo modification each file only for getting the compiled javascrit...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use '`Run file watchers`' command to trigger a watcher for selected folder/project: just select a folder/project root, hit `Ctrl+Shift+A`  -> type "run file " -> choose Run File Watchers.... You can assign custom shortcut for "Plugins | File Watchers | Run File Watchers" action in Settings | Keymap to make this procedure less complicated.

Comment: Ho ! Why this feature is hidden ? Not any word on that in the documentation. Thank you !

Comment: Function not available anymore :(